# Команды ассемблера в 16-ричном эквиваленте

Tags: ассемблер

Мне нужна таблица или просто шпаргалка по командам ассемблера в 16-ричном представлении для 32 и 64 бит. Например команда mov а ее 16-ричное представление 0x00BE (как пример). Почему-то сложно в интернете найти такую таблицу, в основном просто показывают набор инструкций: mov, add, jmp etc. Возможно я написал что-то не так, но надеюсь вы поняли, не эксперт в этом деле.

Comment: google -> `software developer manuals site:intel.com`

Comment: да там мануал на 5000 страниц смотрел я его, я уверен что там где то есть то что мне нужно, но найти нужную страницу проблематично, так и не смог

Comment: Ну тогда ищи просто `x86 opcodes` или `x64 opcodes` - уже на первой странице будут вменяемые ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог этот сайт, довольно все просто и понятно https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly